# Trying to pull the ID when Bootstrap Model shows using Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the ID of each a LISTED data fetched from MySql to UPDATE using a bootstrap model when update button clicks from the same page.

Passed id to the href and converting that to a javascript variable. And using that variable in PHP.

```
<td colspan="2"><a class="btn btn-danger updatebtn" name="updateuser" href="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateuser">Update</a></td>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.updatebtn').click(function() {
      var modelId = $(this).attr('href');
    });
  });

<?php $id1 = "<script>document.write(modelId)</script>"; ?>
```

Comment: what is not `working` ? did you got any `error` ?

Comment: There is no error, but no value is getting for the variable

Comment: You can send your `modelId`using ajax and get that variable in your php page for further processing , Also i suggest you  to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)